# How does 'self' work in Scala actors?

Tags: scala, actor

The following code snippet is taken from Programming in Scala

```
import actors.Actor

object NameResolver extends Actor {

 import java.net.{InetAddress, UnknownHostException}


 def act() {
   react {
     case (name: String, actor: Actor) =>
       actor ! getIp(name)
       act()
     case "EXIT" =>
       println("Name resolver exiting.")
     // quit
     case msg =>
       println("Unhandled message: " + msg)
       act()
   }
 }

 def getIp(name: String): Option[InetAddress] = {
   try {
     Some(InetAddress.getByName(name))
   } catch {
     case _: UnknownHostException => None
   }
 }
}
```

Firstly within react {} what does the recursive call to act() do? It looks like all the cases would fail and it will simply drop through to the end doing nothing.

Secondly in the book, they use the following REPL example

```
NameResolver ! ("www.scala-lang.org", self)
```

Where does 'self' come from? I have tried to replicate this in a main method

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   NameResolver.start()
   NameResolver ! ("www.scala-lang.org", Actor.self)
 }
```

The above does not work

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The above does not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code inside `react` is called only when a **new** message is available. Thus, if you call recursively `act()` inside a `case` clause, the actor will "wait" until a new message is sent (without blocking a thread). It's an alternative to `loop` when you want to change the behavior of the actor according to what it received. Here you stop waiting for messages when you get `"EXIT"`.
2. `self` is supposed to be used **inside** an actor everytime you want to use `this`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `act()` runs recursively, unless you send an `EXIT` message. For any other message that neither match `EXIT` nor `(name: String, actor: Actor)`, `case msg` will be used. In other words `case msg` is a kind of a generic handler that processes all the unmatched messages.
2. `Actor.self` is a [reliable way](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//actors/scala/actors/Actor.scala#L67) to refer to the actor instance *from within an actor's body* (it's recommended to use `self` instead of `this`, to refer to the right instance). In your case, you're calling `Actor.self` not from an actor, and, thus, it fails.